# Node.js code and DB schema differ in their casing style

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm working with a DB that has fields such as "userID" and a Node app that uses "userId" for variables. Is this a good thing or should they be the same?

Comment: It's common for different systems in the stack to have different naming conventions. It's both somewhat common, and can also be frustrating because there's more work to do mapping between systems. There's no real right answer here.

Comment: thx @Evert. but if you have the option, it sounds like you'd make them the same, yes?

Comment: Ultimately this is pretty subjective, but in the past I always kept the naming convention different and other wonder if that's the right thing to do. I'm still not convinced either way.

Comment: However, my approach would at least be to have the database aligned with my code, not the other way around. I think I value 'common coding standards' more and would rather have that then a match with my DB.